# Database Query Takes One Reload After Form Submit To Update

Tags: php, html, mysql, class

I want once a user updates the information on their profiles not to reload  the input boxes instantly.

Here is a example:

```
User updates his age box:
User inputs 10
Displays 10
User inputs 20
Displays 10
Page Reload
Displays 20
```

I do not know why this is happening. It takes a FULL page reload and page refresh for the correct information to be displayed :(

Yet once the information is updated in the database, and I print the information - it is correct. That does not work though sense the button reloads the whole page. Here are the variables getting set:

---

### Variables

```
function utf8_encode_string($value) {
    if (empty($_POST[$value])) {
        $str = "";
        return $str;
    }
    else {
        $str = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST[$value]), ENT_QUOTES));
        return $str;
    }
}

$urlquery = new user("username", $accounturl, $connection); 
$locationinput = utf8_encode_string($urlquery->user_information("location"));
if (!$locationinput) {
    $locationinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($urlquery->user_information("location")), ENT_QUOTES));
}
```

---

### Form

```
<form method="post">
    <input 
        type="text" 
        name="location" 
        id="locationinput" 
        value="<?php print utf8_decode($locationinput); ?>" 
     />
</form>
```

---

### Class

```
class user {

    public function __construct($row_name_1, $row_value_1, $connection) {
        $this->row_name_1 = $row_name_1;
        $this->row_value_1 = $row_value_1;
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }   

    public function user_update_information($updatecolumn, $updatecolumn_value) {
        $query = "UPDATE users SET $updatecolumn = :updatecolumn WHERE $this->row_name_1 = :row_value_1";
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(':updatecolumn' => $updatecolumn_value,
                             ':row_value_1' => $this->row_value_1));
    }

    public function user_information($information) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE $this->row_name_1 = :row_value_1";
        $params = array(':row_value_1' => $this->row_value_1);
        try{
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }
        $columns = $stmt->fetch();
        return $columns[$information];
    }
}
```

---

### Database Update

```
$location_for_database = "";
if (isset($locationinput)) 
{
    $location_for_database = $locationinput;
}
else 
{
    $location_for_database = "";
}

$updateinfo = new user("id", $_SESSION["logged_in"], $connection);
$updateinfo->user_update_information(
    "location", 
    ($location_for_database)
);
```

---

If you would like my full code you can find it here: http://pastebin.com/Cg2LQd7T

Please, let me know if you would like me to explain my issue better. I have been working on this for over a month now, and I can not fix it! :(

Answer (score 0):

i know this is just a :

## work around

but you can use

```
 header("Refresh:0");
```

on the page to reload it just after you are done saving the values in database.

P.S. - THIS IS A WORKAROUND.